# Binding Hyperlink to richtextblock in windows 8 Metro app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am building a windows 8 metro app for fun/learning etc.
I have created a listview of text items that have descriptions, images etc.  Inside the description, there are often hyperlinks that I would like to make clickable.

However, when binding to a textblock, xaml hyperlink code is displayed as text.  Searching arround, it looks like I need to use a richtextblock for hyperlinks.  I can't seem to figure out how to bind a hyperlink to it.  I have found many examples from wpf showing how to extend the richtextblock using flowdocument.  Flowdocument doesn't exist in the current consumer preview version of the framework.

I am reaching out to see if anyone has solved this issue or has any suggestions on what path to head down.

Edit:
Code I have Currently

right now I am just binding the "text" field from my Statuses Object to a textblock binding on "text"

I have URL's in the text field which I want to be able to make clickable.

As a test I was replacing the text field of the first object with hyperlink markup

ex.
feed_results[0].text = "`<hyperlink .....`

then trying to bind to texblock and richtextblock

Xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Background="Black" Width="372" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50,0,0,0">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical"  MinHeight="100">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding user.profile_image_url}" Margin="0,0,15,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding user.name}" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap"  MaxWidth="200" />
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Gray"   Text="{Binding text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  MaxWidth="200" />                      
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel  Margin="0,15,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding created_at,  Converter={StaticResource StringConverter},ConverterParameter=Released: \{0:d\}}"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Gray" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

**Backend Code**

```
FeedResult<Statuses> r2 = await feed.StatusesAsync(1, 50);

            if (!r2.HasError)
            {
                feed_results = r2.Result;


                Dispatcher.Invoke(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, new Windows.UI.Core.InvokedHandler((o, a) =>
                {

                    ItemListView1.ItemsSource = feed_results;
                }), this, null);
            }
```

Comment: Could you show us the code that you currently have?

Comment: In WPF/Silverlight, I'd use a HyperlinkButton if the link is simple enough (just a single text or image). Maybe it is available in Metro too? (I don't have my VS11 handy).

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft removed support for inline hyperlinks from Metro XAML. You can still use [HyperlinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hyperlinkbutton.hyperlinkbutton) for non inline hyperlinks, or if your inline hyperlinks short (1-2 words) then you could place HyperlinkButton inside of InlineUIContainer in RichTextBlock. Later solution would require some code, just using binding won't do it.